# com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 Authentication required Spring Boot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

When I want to send an email through Amazon SES, I get the error, this is my configuration and code:

//ERROR CODE
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "email-smtp.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com", port 465, isSSL true
220 email-smtp.amazonaws.com ESMTP SimpleEmailService-d-9VSVBLD64 0qSZgoJIAdLpaKOxPLSu
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "email-smtp.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com", port: 465

```
250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250 Ok
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "PLAIN LOGIN"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "Ok", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:example@mail.com
530 Authentication required
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 Authentication required

        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1388)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:959)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:583)
        at com.mit.webpaycdmx.email.EmailAmazonSES.send(EmailAmazonSES.java:118)
        at com.mit.webpaycdmx.email.EmailClient.sendEmail(EmailClient.java:54)
        at com.mit.webpaycdmx.services.impl.WebpayCdmxServiceImpl.sendEmail(WebpayCdmxServiceImpl.java:979)
        at com.mit.webpaycdmx.services.impl.WebpayCdmxServiceImpl.paymentResult(WebpayCdmxServiceImpl.java:307)
        at com.mit.webpaycdmx.controllers.WebpayCdmxController.paymentResult(WebpayCdmxController.java:146)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:901)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at com.mit.webpaycdmx.configuration.ClickjackingPreventionFilter.doFilter(ClickjackingPreventionFilter.java:18)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at com.mit.webpaycdmx.configuration.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:42)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:688)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:747)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:615)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:818)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1623)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

MY CODE implementation properties:
// Create a Properties object to contain connection configuration information.
        properties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps";
        properties.put("mail.smtps.port", "465");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.debug", "true");
        properties.put("mail.timeout", 5000);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.user", "someUser");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.password", "somePassword");

//MY METHOD IMPLEMENTATION SEND
public void send() throws MessagingException, IOException  {
        // Create a Session object to represent a mail session with properties.
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, new javax.mail.Authenticator() 
        {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() 
            {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(smtpUserName,smtpP4d);
            }
       });
        session.setDebug(true);
        WebPayCdmxLog.info("\nSessionProperties: " + session.getProperties());
        
        // Create a message with the specified information.
        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from, fromName));
        msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
        msg.setSubject(subject);

        // Create a Multipart message
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        
        // Create and add the html message part
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setContent(body, "text/html");
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        
        // Create and add the attachments part
        for (File attachment : attachments) {
            MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            attachmentPart.attachFile(attachment);
            multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);
        }

        // Add the complete message parts
        msg.setContent(multipart);
        
        // Create a transport.
        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps");
        
        // Send the message.
            log.info("Sending...");

            // Connect to Amazon SES using the SMTP username and password specified
            transport.connect(host, smtpUserName, smtpP4d);

            // Send the email.
            transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
            log.info("Email sent successfully!");
```

Comment: Can you show your code and your POM file. Once setup properly - the Java V2 SES API works perfectly

Comment: Hi smac2020, I am using the jar of JavaMail version 1.4ea, and in the useAuth variable it sets it to me as false, when I am indicating it in the properties:"mail.smtp.auth:true"

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, the Java v2 SES API works fine, once you perform these tasks.

**Setup your creds properly**. To setup creds for Java V2, please refer to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/credentials.html.

**Setup your POM dependencies for this API**. Look at the POM file here. https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/ses/pom.xml

**Setup your SES Service Client properly and use proper Java logic**. To use this API to send an email message, use this AWS Java V2 code:

```
package com.example.ses;

// snippet-start:[ses.java2.sendmessage.request.import]
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.ses.SesClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.ses.model.*;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.ses.model.Message;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.ses.model.Body;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
// snippet-end:[ses.java2.sendmessage.request.import]

/**
 * Before running this Java V2 code example, set up your development environment, including your credentials.
 *
 * For more information, see the following documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */
public class SendMessageEmailRequest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String usage = "\n" +
                "Usage:\n" +
                "    <sender> <recipient> <subject> \n\n" +
                "Where:\n" +
                "    sender - An email address that represents the sender. \n"+
                "    recipient -  An email address that represents the recipient. \n"+
                "    subject - The  subject line. \n" ;

          if (args.length != 3) {
            System.out.println(usage);
             System.exit(1);
           }

        String sender = args[0];
        String recipient = args[1];
        String subject = args[2];

        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        SesClient client = SesClient.builder()
                .region(region)
                .credentialsProvider(ProfileCredentialsProvider.create())
                .build();

        // The HTML body of the email.
        String bodyHTML = "<html>" + "<head></head>" + "<body>" + "<h1>Hello!</h1>"
                + "<p> See the list of customers.</p>" + "</body>" + "</html>";

        try {
            send(client, sender, recipient, subject, bodyHTML);
            client.close();
            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // snippet-start:[ses.java2.sendmessage.request.main]
    public static void send(SesClient client,
                            String sender,
                            String recipient,
                            String subject,
                            String bodyHTML
    ) throws MessagingException {

        Destination destination = Destination.builder()
                .toAddresses(recipient)
                .build();

        Content content = Content.builder()
                .data(bodyHTML)
                .build();

        Content sub = Content.builder()
                .data(subject)
                .build();

        Body body = Body.builder()
                .html(content)
                .build();

        Message msg = Message.builder()
                .subject(sub)
                .body(body)
                .build();

        SendEmailRequest emailRequest = SendEmailRequest.builder()
                .destination(destination)
                .message(msg)
                .source(sender)
                .build();

        try {
            System.out.println("Attempting to send an email through Amazon SES " + "using the AWS SDK for Java...");
            client.sendEmail(emailRequest);

        } catch (SesException e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    // snippet-end:[ses.java2.sendmessage.request.main]
}
```